# Adding LDAP authentication to html static sites

Tags: ldap

Is it possible to add LDAP authentication to static sites?

Comment: Not a Docusaurus-specific issue.

Comment: Static sites using what as an HTTP server? Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

If Tomcat (for example) is hosting your static sites then LDAP can be used to authenticate users. 
[Here is an example of configuration on Apache Tomcat](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/r_ac_tom_ldap.html) to authenticate against an LDAP server, [here is how to integrate LDAP with Tomcat](https://github.com/bhochhi/apache-tomcat-guide/wiki/How-to-integrate-LDAP-with-Tomcat%3F) and [here is Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html). Read the "Realm" or Security Realm configuration in Tomcat.